# HTML <ol> tag left alignment

Tags: reactjs, html, bootstrap-4

My code is not lining up the way i would like

```
    <Row >
      <Col className="person-wrapper">
                            <ol>
                    <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
                    <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
                    <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
                    <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
                    <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
                    <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
                            </ol>
      <Link to="/testing">
        <Button bsStyle="primary">Click Me</Button>
      </Link>
      </Col>
    </Row>
```

This is printing out like this (the _ is blank space)

1. __________________________________       xxxxxxxx
2. __________________________________       xxxxxxxx
3. __________________________________       xxxxxxxx
4. __________________________________       xxxxxxxx
5. __________________________________       xxxxxxxx
6. __________________________________       xxxxxxxx

What i would like to see it this

1. xxxxxxxx
2. xxxxxxxx
3. xxxxxxxx
4. xxxxxxxx
5. xxxxxxxx
6. xxxxxxxx

Comment: there may be some padding or margin

Comment: Can you add the stylesheet or any styling you're using, also is this happening on all browsers?

Comment: I *assume* that `Row` and `Col` will be translated to `<div class="row">` and `<div class="col">` so you should check the stylesheet for rules for `.row, .col` and `.person-wrapper`. Also keep in mind that `ol` has a default padding of 40px.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the styles you are currently using.

Comment: If you are using a style framework or library go into your web inspector and get the style for the elements from there. It will help us to help you.